# How to return value from Ext.Dialog?

Tags: extjs

How to return value from Ext.Dialog? I think this is a very frequent task, but I could never find the appropriate answer.
The two problems that I see here are: 1) how to return value from another dialog, and 2) how to wait for that value from the view the dialog has been called.
As for the first problem, one thing that pops up into my head is to write the value in the viewModel of the caller view, but I have no idea how to wait for that value.

I prepared a simple example, in which I need to create `'MyApp.view.main.MyView'`, but for that I need to know whether user selected A1, A2, A3 or A4.

```
onBtnClick: function(){
    
    //call Dialog
    Ext.create('MyApp.view.main.MyDialog', {}).show();

    //how to get value from dialog and wait for that here?
    
    //then call another view 
    Ext.create('MyApp.view.main.MyView', {
        type: type,
    }).show();
},
```

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.MyDialog', {
    extend: 'Ext.Dialog',
    
    items: [
    {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'A1',
        handler: function(){
            this.up().close();
        }
    },
    {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'A2',
        handler: function(){
            this.up().close();
        }
    },
        {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'A3',
        handler: function(){
            this.up().close();
        }
    },
    {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'A4',
        handler: function(){
            this.up().close();
        }
    }
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom events:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.MyDialog', {
    extend: 'Ext.Dialog',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'A1',
        handler: function () {
            this.up('dialog').fireEvent('dialogbuttonclick', 'A1');
            this.up().close();
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'A2',
        handler: function () {
            this.up('dialog').fireEvent('dialogbuttonclick', 'A2');
            this.up().close();
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'A3',
        handler: function () {
            this.up('dialog').fireEvent('dialogbuttonclick', 'A3');
            this.up().close();
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'A4',
        handler: function (btn) {
            this.up('dialog').fireEvent('dialogbuttonclick', 'A4');
            this.up().close();
        }
    }],
});

Ext.create('MyApp.view.main.MyDialog', {
    listeners: {
        'dialogbuttonclick': function (buttonId) {
            console.log(info.buttonId);
            /*Ext.create('MyApp.view.main.MyView', {
                type: buttonId,
            }).show();*/
        },
    }
}).show();
```

Comment: Thank you Arthur, but I still don't understand how to implement it in the above structure. Could you please just finalize it with how to assign value to variable 'type' from my question?

Comment: There is no "wait" in JS. It is event based. In this case you will create the 'MyApp.view.main.MyView' inside the event handler. 
I have updated the sample.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think that you missed one my post :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68128440/how-to-refresh-grid-column-width-in-extjs-modern-toolkit